# Query to increment a column value on each new record in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to populate a column with an incremented number for each new record I create in a MS Access table. The table already has over 2500 records which have been manually populated.

I'm trying to do this through a SQL query which I plan to call on creation of the new record. In my table, `tblCust` I have a column named `File Number` which I default to `0` so that I don't change every record.

Here's the sort of thing I have tried so far:

```
UPDATE tblCust 
SET tblCust.[File Number] = MAX([tblCust].[File Number]) + 1
WHERE tblCust.[File Number] = 0;
```

When I try running the query I get an error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not specify the expression 'File Number' as part of an aggregate function.

I have tried breaking the query up to see what does work, but as you can see, it's pretty sparse as it is! Any help would be great, thanks for reading :)

Comment: In table design mode, just add a new column to tblCust .  Name it say FileNum without any space in the name, and type AutoIncre.  When you say OK to the change, it will auto number each existing row in that column.  And when new rows are added, it will keep increasing that value in the new row.

Comment: DonPablo, thanks. I can see your solution, though I have some data cleaning to do, if I delete empty records and order my data then I think that will work! I'm away from the office at the moment but will report back. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I underdent you correctly, you want a field that will automatically set an ID(`[File Number]` in your case) for row beginning from 0, 1, 2 ... and so on. You can achieve it by creating `[File Number]` as `AUTOINCREMENT(0,1)`. It will set `[File Number] = 0` for the first row, `[File Number] = 1` for the second and so on.

```
    CREATE TABLE YourTable
    (
    [File Number] AUTOINCREMENT(0,1)
   ,the rest of your columns...
    )
```

Comment: Thanks M Kanarkowski, I'm away from the office at the moment but will check into this. The column is already partially populated so simply changing the column attribute to Auto Number is not an option, but adding another column as suggested by another contributor sounds promising. I'll be sure to report back! Many thanks.